# GHG emissions per company per year (carbon footprint database)

Tags: greenhouse-gases, database, emissions, history

Which countries require corporations to report their GHG emissions (eg tonnes of CO2 [or GWP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_warming_potential) emitted), and where can I find those numbers per company?

I'm trying to find companies who do high-energy industrial manufacturing (eg steel production) with renewable energy power sources.

For example, [Salzgitter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salzgitter) is a major steel producer in Germany that's investing in hydrogen-powered electric arc furnaces powered by wind. I'd like to find-out the amount of steel they produce per year, divide that by the GWP that their production produces each year, and then compare that to other companies in the region (eg [thyssenkrupp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ThyssenKrupp)).

Where can I find the actual GWP produced per company per year?

Comment: See also https://climate.ec.europa.eu/eu-action/climate-strategies-targets/progress-made-cutting-emissions/emissions-monitoring-reporting_en

Comment: Have you tried looking at each company's annual report to stock holders?

Comment: I would be surprised if you find a good source that is global.  Every country would have its own GHG emissions inventory reporting requirements (if any).  I don't know about Germany, but USA is here:  https://www.epa.gov/ghgreporting/ghgrp-emissions-location

Comment: Finding GHG emissions inventory is a different task than finding which companies use renewable power sources.  Those questions should probably be asked separately.  Some companies produce their own power on-site, but most electrical grids are regionally shared, and renewable energy is a portion of the electrical grid power source.  So you might want to be more specific about how you define "uses renewable energy".

Comment: Low emissions iron smelting is more like trial pilot projects, not commercial production. A lot of steelmaking already uses electricity so more renewables lowers emissions and that is happening, but smelting without coke (coal) is in infancy. If it is cost effective it will get taken up. If it isn't it won't be taken up voluntarily: emissions regulation, carbon pricing and or industry support and subsidy.

Comment: @f.thorpe I'm not interested in quantifying their renewable energy usage; I'm interested in quantifying their GHG emissions and amount of product (eg steel) they produce. If  [a] the product produced is high and [b] the GHG emissions are near-zero, then their energy source must not be causing GHG emissions (and therefore it can be assumed they're using renewable [non-fossil-fuel] energy).

Comment: @MichaelAltfield GHG emissions from a facility and GHG emissions from the power source that they use are 2 separate things.  Just because a facility uses wind-power, they could still have lots of GHG emissions, depending on their processes.

Comment: Also, it sounds now like you are looking for net GHG emissions, which is steeped in regulatory definitions, and not the same as "actual" emissions.

Comment: I'm interested in actual total emissions caused by the company -- not a number that's offset by carbon offsets or other political fuckery